# R, Rstudio Console Encoding Windows

Tags: r, windows, encoding, rstudio, locale

I there a way to change the console encoding in Rstudio on windows?

This is not about reading files or sourcing scripts in a specific encoding but about changing the console encoding (the encoding Sys.getlocale yields).

This is usually not a big problem, but i try to create a package and I'm using german umlauts in some strings and symbols. `roxygen2` works best with `UTF-8` encoding but `covr` gives an error if the source files are not in the console/system encoding.

(If there's a workaround for the `roxygen2` and `covr` problem this would also help. Addintional info: I call `covr::package_coverage` from the console and I call `roxygen2` via Rstudios Build command.)

and sessioninfo:

```
sessionInfo()
# R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
# 
# Matrix products: default
# 
# locale:
# [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Austria.1252
```

Update: Sourcing the function that gives an error through the file in Rstudio works, loading with `devtools::load_all(".")` and the RStudio gui gives the error/wrong encoding.

Comment: Do you mean `Sys.setlocale`?

Comment: Yes, but I can't get other Encodings to work, either I get the locale-strings in Windows wrong, or Windows does not support the Encodings is need. Any help or links to documentation of the Windows locales would also help a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're asking how to change the locale to a UTF-8-capable one on Windows, the answer is *you can't*.

When you call `Sys.setlocale`, R will call the `setlocale` system function. Unfortunately, there isn't a way to specify UTF-8 for the character type (`LC_CTYPE`); see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4336010/6233565 .

What you *can* do is change the locale to one of those described at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd373814.aspx . For example, to change to Windows-1251, do

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", ".1251")
```

Hopefully, at some point in the future you will be able to write UTF-8 encoded data on Windows. Currently, that's not possible. All output goes through the native locale: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2017-June/074556.html

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to know. Well I guess I'll have to find some workaround to that.

Comment: It's still not possible to print accented letters correctly with Windows